# Create a stack of folders named from a .txt file

Tags: bash

I have a one column text file (`dates.txt`) and I want to create a stack of directories named after the dates elements.

How can I interpret it in bash?

Answer (score 3):

```
xargs mkdir < dates.txt
```

`xargs` will read the lines of its stdin, and append the lines to the given command. This will minimize the number of times `mkdir` is invoked.

Answer (score 2):

Read in the contents of the file, and make directories for each entry in your data file, like this:

```
while IFS= read -r dat; 
do 
   mkdir "$dat"
done < dates.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

With [`mapfile`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#index-mapfile) (Bash 4.0 or newer):

```
mapfile -t names < dates.txt && mkdir "${names[@]}"
```

This reads the lines into an array `names` and then calls `mkdir` with the expanded, properly quoted array elements as arguments.

The `-t` is required to remove the newline from the end of each element.